# How can I use GenSA package for optimizition a function that its parameters have discrate range?

Tags: spatial, sampling, simulated-annealing

I'm working on spatial sampling design. I should maximize a utility function on a grid.By grid I mean (x,y) that have {0,0.01,0.02,0.03,...,1} values. How can I define these parameter;s range in GenSA function?

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.